# `Cannot get a signed_id for a new record.` with `url_for` after attaching picture in Rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

### When upgrading to Rails 7.1 we are getting an error when trying to use `url_for` in the response when creating a new record.

After creating a chat object with one attached picture, the response includes the url of the attached picture. We are finding that if `url_for(chat.picture)` is used we get the error `ActionView::Template::Error: Cannot get a signed_id for a new record.`

The picture is definitely attached to the chat at this stage.

If we use `chat.picture.url` instead the error is not seen. However, we want to use `url_for` so a relative url is returned.

Our Chat model has `has_one_attached :picture, service: :chat_pictures` and we attach the picture with `@chat.picture.attach(params[:chat][:picture])`

Is there anything we can do differently to avoid this error?

Comment: That's pretty hard to answer without knowing what you're actually doing now.

Comment: 7.1 is a release candidate, if you're seeing a bug you should report it, if you're not sure it's a bug or not then frankly, you shouldn't be testing an RC.

Comment: I'm also seeing this, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards no, we just used chat.picture.url instead. This was helpful though: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/47047

Comment: We got this error too, and it turned out to be because we were using FactoryBot's `build` (which does not save the model to the database), and then trying to get the url. Switching to `create` (which saves the model) worked.